# Lenovo X1 Carbon, Win7 - speakers do not mute when plugging in headphones

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, speakers, headphones

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon running windows 7. 
When I plug in headphones the internal speakers do not mute.
Also, the mic input seems to come from internal mic, even when a headset is connected.

The headphones DO work, but in parallel to the speakers.

I updated my audio drivers from the Lenovo site running version 6.0.1.6710 from 21/Aug/2012.

This is really annoying. Any suggestions that may solve it?

Comment: Are your drivers from Realtek? If yes, then I think I know the answer

Answer (score 1):

this is for windows 8 but should work.  This happened to me and it turned out to be my own error.  If you plug the headphone metal thing in only part of the way, it comes out very tinny on the headphones.  However, once I pushed it a bit more, it had full contact and then stopped the speakers from playing while giving full stereo to the headphones.  Also, check the "Realtek HD Audio Manager" controls.  When I was having the issue, it showed that the analog jack was only in for one out of the 2 connections.  That gave the hint that I needed to be firmer with the jack and push it in more.  Problem solved.